# Composer issue when updating magento version to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2, composer

When I run `composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.5-p1 -W`

I got the following error

```
Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 requires magento/module-catalog 104.0.5-p1 -> found magento/module-catalog[104.0.5-p1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.5-p1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5-p1].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.5-p1].
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What is your composer version?

Comment: Composer version 2.2.5

Comment: Please tell me your current version of Magento which you want to update?

Comment: Current version 2.4.5

Comment: can you share root/composer.json  here in code format?

Comment: I think there is the issue in composer.lock and composer.json can you share?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have another dependency that requires `magento/module-catalog` at a version lower than `104.0.5-p1`.

You should search your `composer.lock` file to try and find which package is requiring `magento/module-catalog` at a version lower than `104.0.5-p1`. Try also running composer require with `-vvv` flag, this should provide more debug information.

Also might help to replace the `-W` flag with `-w`. From composer docs (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md):

> --with-dependencies (-w): Update also dependencies of packages in the argument list, except those which are root requirements.

> --with-all-dependencies (-W): Update also dependencies of packages in the argument list, including those which are root requirements.